# jquery: modify css attribute on element load

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I've been working on a very simple Jquery script that displays a few mini-dashboards (divs) for users. When someone clicks a link the correct panel is displayed. Very much like Twitter's login panel.

I have a couple issue I can't sort out with my current script:

1. If someone disables Javascript then each panel should still work. So in my css file I have something like `a #panel1 {display:none;}` and then `a:hover #panel1 {display:block;}`. Now when my page loads jquery needs to change a:hover to display:none instead or disable it. Also is there a way to make this happen as soon as the element is rendered?
2. I've also tried to bind event mouseup to document to close the panel but it's not working.

account-menu.js

```
(function($){
    $.fn.renderDash = function(openDash, fn) {
        var container = $(this);

        container.bind('click', function(event){event.preventDefault();clickStart();})
                 .bind('mouseup', function(event){mouseupDash();})
                 .bind('mouseover', function(event){hoverDash();})
                 .bind('mouseout', function(event){hoverDash();})

        $(document).bind('mouseup', function(event){
            if($(event.target).$(parent(container)).length==0) {
                   $(openDash).hide();
            }
        })   

        function clickStart() {
            $(openDash).toggle();
        }

        function mouseupDash() {
            return false;
        }

        function hoverDash() {
            return false;
        }


    };
})(jQuery);
```

index.html

```
...
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="account-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.panel1-start').renderDash("#panel1");
        $('.panel2-start').renderDash("#panel2");
        $('.panel3-start').renderDash("#panel3");
    });
</script>
...
</head>

<body>
...
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="panel1-start">Panel 1 Link</a>
        <ul id="panel1">
            <li>Panel 1 Content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
panel2, panel3, etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a no-js class to the anchor tag.

```
a:hover #panel1 { display:none }
a.no-js:hover #panel1 { display:block }
```

Then with jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.no-js').removeClass('no-js');
});
```

And that function will initiate then the DOM is ready. That way if JS is enabled it will always be `display:none` and you have a fallback for non javascript users (no-js).

Or you could do vise versa and use `.addClass` with jQuery.

```
a:hover #panel1 { display:block }
a.js-en:hover #panel1 { display:none }

$(function() {
    $('#panel1').parent().addClass('js-en');
});
```

Though I would highly suggest the `removeClass` function, either that or you designate a class to the anchor tag. Or possibly:

```
<a rel="panel" href="#"><span id="panel1"></span></a>

a[rel="panel"]:hover #panel1 { display:block; }
a.js-en:hover #panel1 { display:none }

$(function() {
    $('a[rel="panel"]').addClass('js-en');
});
```

Comment: Of course! why didn't I think of that! Don't suppose you have an answer to the second part too?

Comment: Edited, added another alternative too ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a:hover #panel1").css("display","none");
```

this will override you stylesheet style with jquery.

```
//edits

    //for a variable as long as it is an object
    openDash.css("display","none");

    //and to perform it on page load
    $(document).ready(function(){
        openDash.css("display","none");
    });
```

Comment: can I replace #panel1 with variable openDash instead somehow?

Comment: also does this happen as soon as the element is rendered or does it wait until the whole page loads?